# nullPointerException error greenfoot

Tags: nullpointerexception, greenfoot

I'm working on a project for an intro to programming class, and I've run into a slight problem. We're making a side scroller, and I'm working on the score counter right now. My issue is that when I try to create a reference to the counter class in anything other than the act method(called once every frame) I get a null pointer exception error. You can download the zip file with my code in it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t2yb0epse7s0g15/Space%20game.zip?dl=0) if you want to take a look.

EDIT:
Here's the offending code:

```
public class HeroMissile extends Missiles
```

{

```
/**
 * Act - do whatever the HeroMissile wants to do. This method is called whenever
 * the 'Act' or 'Run' button gets pressed in the environment.
 */
public void act() 
{
    move(8);
    remove();
}    

public void remove() {
    if(isTouching(Drone.class)) {
        removeTouching(Drone.class);
        getWorld().addObject(new Explosion(), getX(), getY());
        getWorld().removeObject(this);
        addScore();
        return;
    }
}

public void addScore() {
    City cityWorld = (City) getWorld();
    **Counter scoreCounter = cityWorld.getCounter();**
    scoreCounter.add(1);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `getWorld()` [in `addScore()`] after you removed yourself from the world.  In this case, `getWorld()` will return null, so you will get a null pointer exception.  Try changing the order in `remove()` to add the score before you remove yourself from the world.